# Web Tools 2012.2 LESS Compile on Build

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less

I am using Web Tools 2012.2 and I have the following LESS files:

- styles.less
- styles.common.less
- styles.forms.less
- styles.grids.less

styles.less contains

```
@import-once "styles.common.less";
@import-once "styles.forms.less";
@import-once "styles.grids.less";
```

If I make a change in one of the included files, the only way I can get styles.css to update is to make a change and save it.

There is no "Web Tools" tabs under options. I have set Web Essentials > LESS > Compile on Build to True, but it still does not update styles.css when I build.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: Sort of. Instead of the base styles.less file, I am using the bundling built into MVC to combine all my LESS generated CSS at runtime.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Just filed an [issue](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/319).

Comment: As of LESS version 1.4 the `@import`-once directive is removed and is now default behaviour for the `@import` directive